# Is there a way using TracePoint in ruby 2.0 to get the time between call and return of methods?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I'm trying to figure out if I can get the time it takes for a method to execute using TracePoint in ruby 2.0.  Any help is appreciated.

---

### Update

I want to clarify this question.  My goal is to get the time it takes for all methods to execute even if you don't know what those methods will be.  I've found this to be quite tricky.  Deivid's response below involves setting a t0 and t1 variables in a shared context, then setting the time values on call and return.  While this works for a simple example, it becomes unmanageable when trying to log the time of all method calls in a more complex ruby program.  Take for example the following program:

```
class C
  def self.slow
    C.fast
    sleep 3
  end

  def self.fast
  end
end

C.slow
```

In this program, it is only possible to monitor t0 and t1 times if you keep track of the method names being called.  In an even more complex program such as a Rails app with many stack frames where you do not know in advance all of the methods that will be executed, it is not as obvious as to the best way to monitor and print all call and return times.

The solution 'may' involve keeping a hash of call times where the key is some combination of the Thread.current.object_id and the tp.method_id.. I have not found the correct key though that is unique enough to ensure that the return time can be matched to the caller, considering you may have recursive method calls that create non-standard call and return situations.

Answer (score 2):

```
class C
  def self.slow n
    return C.fast if n == 0
    sleep 1
    slow n-1
  end

  def self.fast
  end
end

@times = {}

traceCall = TracePoint.new(:call, :return) do |tp|
  key = "#{tp.defined_class}_#{tp.method_id}_#{caller(0).size}"
  if tp.event == :call
    @times[key] = Time.now
  else
    @times[key] = Time.now - @times[key]
  end
end.enable do
  C.slow 3
end

p @times
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  While your answer does give the execution time as I asked, I've clarified my question to be a bit more specific.  In a non-trivial ruby application with many stack frames with many calls (which you many not know ahead of time), it is more difficult to keep track of call and return times (more difficult then just setting a t0 method).  Any more insight is appreciated.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read your new edit... You are right, for more complicated cases you need more complicated code... :) Good luck!!

Comment: Thanks @deivid, that may be it :) I will need to think about it though. Are there any known issues with that in your mind?